# How to include a large number exhibits

Tags: legal-writing

I have been struggling to find the best way to mention and list the enclosures for a complex complaint/dispute letter to my financial institution. I have to include at least 45 documents. Should I name or number each one then make a list of these after my signature?

Answer (score 1):

One might say at an appropriate point in your letter, "I have attached an index marked as Exhibit 1 to this letter and forty five exhibits, marked and numbered as Exhibits 2-46 to this letter, in support of this complaint.", and then attach the referenced index exhibit and mark and number each subsequent exhibit.